# debugging __do_global_dtors_aux to find code location

Tags: c++, gdb, valgrind, fastcgi

I am trying to find a bug. Using gdb I can see:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007f4325cc286f in std::ostream::flush() () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f4325cc286f in std::ostream::flush() () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x00007f4325c8d31c in std::ios_base::Init::~Init() () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007f4325462995 in __cxa_finalize (d=0x7f432451c458) at cxa_finalize.c:56
#3  0x00007f432430ee86 in __do_global_dtors_aux () from /usr/lib/libsocketxx.so.1.2
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

However I have no clue where in the code the construction/destruction of global variables is causing issues. Furthermore gdb seems incapable of using debug libs and show line numbers:

```
$ gdb
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.3-debian
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
(gdb) show debug-file-directory
The directory where separate debug symbols are searched for is "/usr/lib/debug".
(gdb) attach 10681
[...]
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libsocketxx.so.1.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libsocketxx.so.1.2.0...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libsocketxx.so.1.2
```

I cannot seems to get any more info using valgrind:

```
$ valgrind --tool=exp-sgcheck  --trace-children=yes spawn-fcgi -f /usr/lib/server/server.fcgi -p 9000  -n 
==14248== exp-sgcheck, a stack and global array overrun detector
==14248== NOTE: This is an Experimental-Class Valgrind Tool
==14248== Copyright (C) 2003-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks Ltd et al.
==14248== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14248== Command: spawn-fcgi -f /usr/lib/server/server.fcgi -p 9000 -n
==14248== 
==14248== exp-sgcheck, a stack and global array overrun detector
==14248== NOTE: This is an Experimental-Class Valgrind Tool
==14248== Copyright (C) 2003-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks Ltd et al.
==14248== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14248== Command: /bin/sh -c exec\ /usr/lib/server/server.fcgi
==14248== 
==14248== exp-sgcheck, a stack and global array overrun detector
==14248== NOTE: This is an Experimental-Class Valgrind Tool
==14248== Copyright (C) 2003-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks Ltd et al.
==14248== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14248== Command: /usr/lib/server/server.fcgi
==14248== 
==14248== 
==14248== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==14248==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x7685B0E78C376F24
==14248==    at 0x7685B0E78C376F24: ???
==14248==    by 0x65060EC: std::ostream::flush() (ostream.tcc:219)
==14248==    by 0x64C72FE: std::ios_base::Init::~Init() (ios_init.cc:131)
==14248==    by 0x6C5F994: __cxa_finalize (cxa_finalize.c:56)
==14248==    by 0x7EA3E85: ??? (in /usr/lib/libsocketxx.so.1.2.0)
==14248==    by 0x7EAC760: ??? (in /usr/lib/libsocketxx.so.1.2.0)
==14248==    by 0x6C5F611: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:78)
==14248==    by 0x6C5F664: exit (exit.c:100)
==14248==    by 0x6C47C93: (below main) (libc-start.c:260)
==14248== 
==14248== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 95 from 91)
```

How would you track this kind of bug ?

EDIT:

I have been able to use debug symbols package, so full backtrace is now:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Reading in symbols for ../../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/src/ostream-inst.cc...done.
0x00007f7711d98dc7 in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::pubsync (this=0x7fff6f2e8250)
    at /build/buildd-gcc-4.4_4.4.5-8-amd64-za8kXx/gcc-4.4-4.4.5/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/streambuf:248
248       pubsync() { return this->sync(); }
Current language:  auto
The current source language is "auto; currently c++".
(gdb) bt full
Reading in symbols for ../../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/src/ios_init.cc...done.
Reading in symbols for cxa_finalize.c...done.
#0  0x00007f7711d98dc7 in std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::pubsync (this=0x7fff6f2e8250)
    at /build/buildd-gcc-4.4_4.4.5-8-amd64-za8kXx/gcc-4.4-4.4.5/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/streambuf:248
No locals.
#1  0x00007f7711d8e0ed in std::ostream::flush (this=0x6247e0 <_ZSt4cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4>)
    at /build/buildd-gcc-4.4_4.4.5-8-amd64-za8kXx/gcc-4.4-4.4.5/build/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/ostream.tcc:219
        __err = std::_S_goodbit
#2  0x00007f7711d4f2ff in std::ios_base::Init::~Init (this=0x7f77105b16d0 <_ZStL8__ioinit>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at ../../../../../src/libstdc++-v3/src/ios_init.cc:131
No locals.
#3  0x00007f7711518995 in __cxa_finalize (d=0x7f77105b1620) at cxa_finalize.c:56
        check = <optimized out>
        cxafn = 0x6247e0 <_ZSt4cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4>
        cxaarg = 0x7fff6f2e8250
        f = 0x7f771183f350 <initial+80>
            funcs = 0x7f771183f300 <initial>
#4  0x00007f77103a2316 in __do_global_dtors_aux () from /tmp/inst/usr/lib/libsocketxx.so.1.2
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
```

Comment: found this link but not sure if it is of any help  http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=436231

Comment: Try adding breakpoints constructors for classes declared in global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not find a way to debug this case, however I found the actual issue. When using fcgi you should never do something like this:

```
int main(void) {
    // Backup the stdio streambufs
    streambuf * cin_streambuf  = cin.rdbuf();
    streambuf * cout_streambuf = cout.rdbuf();
    streambuf * cerr_streambuf = cerr.rdbuf();

    FCGX_Request request;

    FCGX_Init();
    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);

    while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0) {
        fcgi_streambuf cin_fcgi_streambuf(request.in);
        fcgi_streambuf cout_fcgi_streambuf(request.out);
        fcgi_streambuf cerr_fcgi_streambuf(request.err);

        cin.rdbuf(&cin_fcgi_streambuf);
        cout.rdbuf(&cout_fcgi_streambuf);
        cerr.rdbuf(&cerr_fcgi_streambuf);

        // [YOUR CODE]
        if( condition) return 1; // NEVER DO THIS
    }

    // restore stdio streambufs
    cin.rdbuf(cin_streambuf);
    cout.rdbuf(cout_streambuf);
    cerr.rdbuf(cerr_streambuf);

    return 0;
}
```